# What is deepest fossil we have found?

Tags: fossils, stratigraphy, geologic-layers

Deepest as in has had the most sediment above it. Obviously it has to be exposed to be found but it's still considered deep if its previously been covered by sediment. I should mention im not looking for cases where they've drilled holes deep in the earth and found microorganisms I mean situations where the fossil was once on the surface then got covered by sediment.

Comment: Difficult to follow your logic ; So you don't count the unlimited numbers of small fossils brought to the surface from say 25,000 ft depth which are routinely examined  while drilling wells to determine the age, , etc, of formations that were previously on the surface ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 I do count it so long as it can be determined these small fossils were once on the surface

Comment: @Shannon Do you actually want the original organism to have been "on the surface", rather than the fossil itself?  Or are you asking about fossils that were reburied after being exposed by erosion? What about fossils that formed on the ocean bottom?

Comment: Fossils are regularly observed in rock cores that are extracted during drilling operations such as those for hydrocarbons. For example here is an example of a fossil fish being dicsovered during drilling at a depth of 1300m https://blog.everythingdinosaur.co.uk/blog/_archives/2007/09/08/3214858.html